# Specific position / Restricted permutation [I don't exactly know the name of this topic]

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In the word ARTICLE find the number of permutation by keeping A in the first place or not keeping E in the last place.

How do I solve this. What's the exact category for this type of permutation? Where can I find problems like this one?

Comment: You can use the [inclusion exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to count the permutations that satisfy one of the two properties.

Comment: Basic combinatorics.

Answer (score 2):

Try to count the opposite: The number of permutations with A not in the first place AND with E in the last place.

There are 6! permutations with E in the last place. From the remaining 6 letters there are 5! with A in the first place (all permutations of RTICL). So we have 6!-5! permutations with A not in the first place and E in the last place. The total number of permutations is 7! so the result is: 7!-6!+5!